# Preserve symbolic link in mocha js

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

In node, if you want to preserve symbolic link when you run a script only add the flag: `node --preserve-symlinks index.js` I think to use the same thing using mocha js for a test, but this not work, in docs, I can't found how to use this flag or alternative flag for testing purposes and keep the symbolic links to another repository in node_modules.

I try this to, without success:

```
"test": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--preserve-symlinks & mocha --recursive --exit",
```

```js
"test": "mocha --preserve-symlinks --recursive --exit",
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem,
this was my original script:

```
   "test:unit": "mocha --opts mocha.opts --timeout 30000 \"test/unit/**/*.js\"",
```

changed it to this:

```
   "test:unit": "node --preserve-symlinks ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --opts mocha.opts --timeout 30000 \"test/unit/**/*.js\""
```

And it works! :)

Answer (score 1):

Without more explanation of your project structure I cannot say why `--preserve-symlink` is not working for you, but the following command will run Mocha while preserving the symlinks:

```
mocha --preserve-symlinks --exit
```